# newbie: activerecord compare object.count with value throws undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, object, activerecord, compare

```
def has_photo

if user_signed_in?

  @user = User.where(:id => current_user.id).first

  if @user.has_photo?
    if Asset.where(:attachable_id => current_user.id).count < 4

      def sub_layout
        "application"
      end

      render :template => "profiles/no_photo"

    end
  end
end
```

end

What would be the correct way to compare the Asset.count ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asset.where is a query, you would be much better using relationships for this.

If

```
Class User
  has_many :assets
end

Class Asset
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You could just use:

```
@user.assets.count < 4
```

As long as Asset has a user_id field (or make the relationship use :attachable_id) that is correctly set (the relationship can do that too if you create the Asset correctly)

By the way, if :id is unique for each user (it should be) you can rewrite

```
@user = User.where(:id => current_user.id).first
```

as

```
@user = User.find(current_user.id)
```

Hope it helps